# What to do with paper savings bonds?

Tags: savings-bonds

My kids get paper savings bonds from family members for holidays/birthdays/etc. Right now I do nothing with them besides putting them in a fire proof lock box but that can't be the best thing to do. What should I do with paper savings bonds?

Comment: Side note - read the rules on cashing in those EE bonds. I remember I couldn't cash in a majority of mine to pay for college but instead needed to do a regular sell. There's all kinds of rules regarding whose names can be on them, how long held, etc. I just cashed most of mine when I was po'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US Treasury has a way of converting paper bonds to electronic bonds: http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/smartexchangeinfo.htm

> SmartExchange allows TreasuryDirect account owners to convert their Series E, EE and I Bonds to electronic securities in a special Conversion Linked Account within their online account. With a TreasuryDirect account, you enjoy all the benefits of having online 24-hour access to manage your holdings, without having to keep track of paper securities.